# Copy-File vs XCopy

Tags: c#, xcopy, processstartinfo

I am trying copy a file via xcopy under startup. But it doesn't work.

Here is code:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi2 = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"xcopy.exe", @"E:\Debug\VipBat\* C:\\Users\\VCCS\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\" /s /i /y");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi2);
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is what a user would say, right before I sigh deeply and ask them for more information.

Comment: That's too bad. You need to make it work. *(Hint: this comment was about as helpful as your error description)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :** You are misusing double quotes here => `Startup\"`

**Soultion :** you need to properly pass arguments to [Process.StartInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Your first parameter should be file name and second parameter should be arguments.

Try This:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi2 = new   
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"xcopy.exe", "E:\\Debug\\VipBat\\* \"C:\\Users\\VCCS\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\\" /s /i /y");
```

Comment: You need \" \" around the second path since it has a space in it and will be counted as two different arguments otherwise.

Comment: it doesn't work too. I think, there is a problem with escape character, like "Start Menu". I don't know how can I solve it.

Comment: @pmacnaughton: you are right i overlooked it.

Comment: @user3313131: you can check my edited answer, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

```
Using System.IO;

public void Copy(string filePath,string DestPath)
{
    if(File.Exists(filePath))
    {
       File.Copy(filePath,DestPath);
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show("The file doesn't exists.","Error") 
    }
}
```